# Pass __int64 to CreateThread Parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, int64

I would like to pass an __int64 as a parameter to my Thread. Here's my current code:

```
void thisismymainfunc( ..., __int64 license, ... )
{
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, checkLicBan, (LPVOID)license, NULL, NULL);
}
```

the code to the thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI checkLicBan(LPVOID m2dlic)
{
    cout << (__int64)m2dlic << endl;
```

the orginal __int64 is:

```
640810053458582
```

cout-ed int is:

```
932995186
```

Could anyone tell me how could I pass such big number to my thread?

Thank you!

Comment: You pass a pointer to it. In general, you make a struct that has everything you want to pass in and pass a pointer in through that parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't cast the 64 bit integer to a pointer. In 32bit applications that will chop it in half. What you're printing is the bottom half of the integer that fits into a 32bit pointer (thanks to the magic of little endian)

You either want to pass in the address of a persistent (and thread safe) 64 bit integer like this

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, checkLicBan, &my_persistent_64bit_integer, NULL, NULL);
```

And then access it like this

```
DWORD WINAPI checkLicBan(LPVOID m2dlic)
{
    cout << *((__int64*)m2dlic) << endl;
```

Or, if you can't persist the value, dynamically allocate it and delete it in your handler like this

```
void thisismymainfunc( ..., __int64 license, ... )
{
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, checkLicBan, new __int64(license), NULL, NULL);
}
```

And then access it like this

```
DWORD WINAPI checkLicBan(LPVOID m2dlic)
{
    __int64* pval = (__int64*)m2dlic
    __int64 myval = *pval;
    delete pval;

    cout << myval << endl;
```